# java.lang.VerifyError in struts2

Tags: spring, hibernate, struts2

I have developed a strut2-spring-hibernate web application.Build is successful but while deploying in tomcat I am getting the following error:

```
Caused by: java.lang.VerifyError: class org.hibernate.type.WrappedMaterializedBl
obType overrides final method getReturnedClass.()Ljava/lang/Class;
at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method) ~[na:1.7.0_09]
at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:791) ~[na:1.7.0_09]
```

Please help....

Comment: Post more info as for with this snippet of log is difficult to make predictions about your problem.

Comment: Probably a version mismatch error.

Comment: this is the stack trace :::::::::::::org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Could not instantiate bean class [org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration]: Constructor threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.VerifyError: class org.hibernate.type.WrappedMaterializedBlobType overrides final method getReturnedClass.()Ljava/lang/Class;
at org.springframework.beans.BeanUtils.instantiateClass(BeanUtils.java:162) ~[spring-beans-3.1.2.RELEASE.jar:3.1.2.RELEASE]

Comment: @Roman C ::: which version mismatch are you talking about?Please help me with the error

Comment: now I am getting this exception when i changed the version of  hibernate to 4:: o.s.web.context.ContextLoader - Context initializationfailed
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: Unexpected exception parsing XML document from ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml]; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/w3c/dom/Elemen
tTraversal
atorg.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.doLoadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:412) ~[spring-beans-3.1.2.RELEASE.jar:3.1.2.RELEASE]

Comment: Ok, try to find Elemen tTraversal in jars

Comment: You need to use Maven or its equivalent. You've either put some of your app's jars in the Tomcat library, or are deploying multiple versions of the same classes, or are mixing dependency versions.

Comment: Also, please put the stack traces *in the original post*, not as comments; it's very difficult to read them there.

Answer (score 0):

It happens when you have multiple versions of jars added in your maven dependency(mismatch of jar versions),

**Caused by: java.lang.VerifyError: class ** so check your maven dependency.

for spring you can find all the dependencies [here](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework)

for hibernate you can find all the dependencies [here](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.hibernate)

for struts you can find all the dependencies [here](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.struts)